# How to destrucure data that changes with axios request in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, destructuring

When I make a api call the following format is set up. The single letter will change based on what I put in the url of the api call.

```
{
"b": {
      data: "data"
      data: "data"
      data: "data"
     }
}
```

This is the following function to get the data from the api:

```
     let changeableUrl = `${rootUrl}?apikey=${apikey}&symbol=${symbol}`;
          useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(changeableUrl).then((result) => {
              setData(result.data);
              setLoading(false);
            });
          }, []);
          if (isLoading) {
            return <div className='App'>Loading...</div>;
          }
          console.log(data);
          return <h1></h1>;
    }
```

A user can enter in a symbol, and the key changes in the request based on the symbol they input. In the example above, I put in the symbol

How can I retrieve this data?

Comment: No, you cannot destructure based on a variable key. For a given URL will the key always be the same? Will you show us your function that uses axios to make the request as well as some examples of how you call it? These details will help us provide relevant suggestions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code snippet so you can format it for readability.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let changeableUrl = `${rootUrl}?apikey=${apikey}&symbol=${symbol}`;
          useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(changeableUrl).then(({data}) => {
               const results = data[`${symbol}`]
              setData(result);
             
              setLoading(false);
            });
          }, []);
          if (isLoading) {
            return <div className='App'>Loading...</div>;
          }
          console.log(data);
          return <h1></h1>;
    }
```

You should try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Please add some words to explain how this solves the problem. Also `data[\`${symbol}\`]` can be reduced to `data[symbol]`.

Comment: I have tried logging data and results, but they both end up being undefined.